# parking ticket in Norway, what happens if I don't pay?

Tags: norway, fines

So we stopped in the Norwegian city of Sandvika for a brief swim (highly recommended) and when we returned to the car about two hours later there was a parking ticket behind the windshield wiper, written out by the Baerum Kommune Vei og Trafikk.

We gathered from the sign in the parking lot that a parking disc was enough but apparently we were wrong and we should have instead bought a parking ticket at that hour of the day.

I'm not disputing the fine in any way but at the same time I'm not keen on paying the, IMO, excessive amount of 660 NOK.

It is my own car, not a rental. Are there any repercussions if I decide to simply not pay the parking ticket, given that Norway isn't a EU country and mine is (Belgium) so it might not be able to request my personal details?

Even though I had a great vacation I'm not planning on visiting Norway again in the upcoming years.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I would point out that Norway **is** a member of the [Schengen Information System](https://knowledge4policy.ec.europa.eu/dataset/ds00009_en).

Comment: Was this your car or a hire car?

Comment: @CMaster: I updated the question to clarify that it is my own car, not a rental.

Comment: NOK 660 hardly seems excessive, especially if you compare it to fines in some EU countries (e.g. the Netherlands) and consider Norway's level of income. I get the urge not to pay but you could spare us the half-baked excuses.

Comment: Note that Norway is collaborating closely with the EU in many areas. I couldn't find any clear documentation in a quick search but I think it might actually be part of the agreement on the mutual recognition of fines. At the same time, the system originally only covered speeding tickets, not parking tickets but I am not sure whether that's still the case.

Comment: @Relaxed: ok then but I disagree.

Comment: @JanVandenbosch Then please explain why you find the fee excessive. In Belgium penalties for illegal parking start at 50€, in Norway 330 kroner or about 33€. In both countries, higher fees are imposed for more severe parking violations. In Norway, the average income is about 70% higher than in Belgium.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: I find it excessive because 1) exactly, I don't have the income of a Norwegian and 2) there's no way illegal parking in Belgium starts at €50 as in a lot of cases, cities have their own parking policies and where I live, will fine much less (€25).

Comment: I have downvoted this question, because it asks advice for evading the law.  I do find the fine excessively low.  For comparison, a public transport ticket inspection fine in Oslo is 1150 NOK, so once again, drivers are cheaper off compared to people using public transportation.

Comment: @gerrit There have been recent changes, but in Germany it is also like that. Not long ago, you only risked a 35€ fine (although potentially to be towed) if you parked so that a tram could not pass. If you rode on the tram without a valid ticket, you would have been fined 60€.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Yes, Germany is also like that.  You can even be [jailed for using public transportation without a ticket](https://www.berliner-zeitung.de/news/berlin-schwarzfahrer-koennen-wieder-ins-gefaengnis-li.231927).

Answer (score 6):

The website of the [Bærum municipality](https://www.baerum.kommune.no/tjenester/vei-trafikk-og-parkering/parkering/parkeringsgebyr-og-kontrollsanksjon/) says :

> Betalingsfrist er tre uker fra ileggelsesdato. Dersom kontrollsanksjonen ikke betales innen fristen, kan den inndrives som et alminnelig pengekrav. Det kan ikke tas særskilte gebyr for inndriving av kontrollsanksjon, utover det som eventuelt måtte følge av annen lovgivning.

Translated in English by Google Translate :

> The deadline for payment is three weeks from the date of imposition. If the control sanction is not paid within the deadline, it can be recovered as a general monetary claim. No separate fee can be charged for the recovery of a control sanction, beyond what may be required by other legislation.

Which means that they can (and likely will) submit the details to a collection agency and then the collection agency will try to get the money from you.

As this is not a traffic fine (parking seems to be under the cities jurisdiction), you seem that you aren't risking any more penalty (An unpaid `NOK`660 traffic fine fine could land you in jail for 3 days under Norwegian [law](https://lovdata.no/forskrift/1990-06-29-492/%C2%A73) for example)

You may be sent to court by the collections agency though, and have to pay a way higher fine down the line, this is an unknown however.

If it is your car, you *could* wait for the collection agency.

But if it is a rental car, I would advise against skipping that fine and just prefer paying it outright, as the rental company will find out and request that fine money from you along with a sizable fee.

Answer (score 6):

Just an addition to Nicolas Formichella's basically correct answer, but too long for a comment:

Penalties for parking violations are in Norway not court imposed fines (and therefore not covered by EU agreements covering the collection of fines) but in practice rather comparable to civil claims. They are imposed either by the municipality (as in this case) or private parking lot operators.

If you don't pay the fee, most Norwegian municipalities will for foreign vehicles hand over the claim to the collection agency Euro Parking Collection plc and they will find you and send you a new claim with a not unsubstantial collection fee added on top of the original claim. If you ignore that claim, you must expect that EPC will initiate whatever legal processes are common in Belgium to enforce payment of civil debts.

Not related to your question, but just an advice: If you should have outstanding toll payments in Norway, you are also likely to hear from EPC about that as well.